# using electrod/nuXmv solver with Alloy on Windows?

Tags: alloy

I have nuXmv installed and added to my path on windows but have not seen instructions anywhere for adding it to the options->solvers menu on windows.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, as soon, as I've added `nuXmv`'s bin folder to my path and restarted Alloy, it appeared in the list of available solvers. Make sure that you can run it in command line as `nuXmv`